# Let $g \in N_G(H)$ an element of order $5$. Compute the order of $H \langle g \rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $G = A_5$ and $H=\langle(1,2,3,4,5)\rangle$.
Let $g \in N_G(H)$ an element of order $5$. Compute the order of $H \langle g \rangle$.

I think I can use the second isomorphism theorem to solve this problem. I find that $|HK| = \frac {|H||\langle g \rangle|}{|H \cap \langle g \rangle|}$, but I don't know how to find $H \cap \langle g \rangle$.

Is anyone is able to give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the subgroups $H$ and $<g>$ are of order 5 which is prime, so either they are equal, or their intersection is trivial.

EDIT: full solution

Since $g$ has order 5 and it is in $A_n$ it must be a 5-cycle. If $g\notin H$, then $H\cap <g>=\{e\}$ since they are both subgroups of prime order, and then you get that $<H,g>$ is a group of order 25 (because $<H,g>\cong H\rtimes <g>$ using the normality of $H$ in $<H,g>$). This is not possible, since $|A_5|=5!/2=60$ is not divisible by 25. It therefore follows that $g$ must be in $H$.

Comment: Which fact allow you to conclude this point? I'm looking carefully, I didn't find out why.

Comment: @J.G a group of prime order has only two subgroups - the whole group and the trivial group $\{e\}$

Comment: I understand, but according to the exercise, $g$ is supposed to be in $H$. How can I show that with the fact that $g \in N_G(H)$

Comment: @J.G : added the full solution